# Date formatting in chr when concatenating CSV files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, tableau-api

I've got an issue with the below function mergeit2.

The function is concatenating two files together.

A current year file and a historic file. In the historic file, the dates are in chr(10) format whilst in the current file the dates are in date format. As I'm then loading the data in Tableau, I want to translate all dates to chr(10) format by recognising the column as str column. However, this keeps failing for some reason. Should I replace my str recognition for another command?

My code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import time
import numpy as np

def mergeit2(path1, path2):
             for fl in path1:
                    df = pd.read_csv(fl, header = None, skiprows = 0)
                    df = df.replace(to_replace = 'Date', value = np.nan).dropna()
                    dflist.append(df)
             concat2 = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 0)
             concat2.to_csv(path2,header = cols, index = False)
             df = pd.read_csv(path2)
             df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
             df.to_csv(path2, index = False)

cols = ['Year','Month','Week','Week in Number','Date','GPU Util%','CPU Util%']
dflist = []
path1 = glob.iglob('C:\*Users\<username>..<rest of path>..\*Data_*.csv')
path2 = "C:\\Users\\<username>..<rest of path>..\\Data_master.csv"
mergeit2(path1,path2)
```

An Example Dataset is:

Before Code Execution:

```
Current file Example Data
Int   int     Str     int            datetime64   float        float
Year    Month   Week    Week in Number  Date    GPU Util%   CPU Util%
2020    1   First   1        01/01/2020   0.680           0.450
2020    1   First   1        02/01/2020   0.320           0.056
2020    1   First   1        03/01/2020   0.560           0.470
2020    1   First   1        04/01/2020   0.520           0.325
Historic File Example Data
int   int     Str     int            chr(10)       float          float
Year    Month   Week    Week in Number  Date    GPU Util%   CPU Util%
2019    1   First   1        05/01/2020   0.467           0.284
2019    1   Second  2        06/01/2020   0.516           0.360
2019    1   Second  2        07/01/2020   0.501           0.323
2019    1   Second  2        08/01/2020   0.494           0.322
```

After Code Execution (merged CSV master file - some dates in chr(10) and others in datetime format)

```
Year    Month   Week    Week in Number  Date    GPU Util%   CPU Util%
2020    1   First   1        2020-01-01   0.680           0.450
2020    1   First   1        2020-01-02   0.320           0.056
2020    1   First   1        2020-01-03   0.560           0.470
2020    1   First   1        2020-01-04   0.520           0.325
int   int     Str     int            chr(10)       float          float
2019    1   First   1        05/01/2020   0.467           0.284
2019    1   Second  2        06/01/2020   0.516           0.360
2019    1   Second  2        07/01/2020   0.501           0.323
2019    1   Second  2        08/01/2020   0.494           0.322
```

My Expected Output is as follows:

```
Int   int     Str     int            chr(10)     float           float
Year    Month   Week    Week in Number  Date    GPU Util%   CPU Util
2020    1   First   1        01/01/2020   0.680           0.450
2020    1   First   1        02/01/2020   0.320           0.056
2020    1   First   1        03/01/2020   0.560           0.470
2020    1   First   1        04/01/2020   0.520           0.325
2019    1   First   1        05/01/2020   0.467           0.284
2019    1   Second  2        06/01/2020   0.516           0.360
2019    1   Second  2        07/01/2020   0.501           0.323
2019    1   Second  2        08/01/2020   0.494           0.322
```

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file. Could you show the same lines as they are in the file?

Comment: Hi, do you mean posting the datasets again with the comma delimiter? Both CSV files are created from multiple Excel files and I have not specified a delimiter in first place.

Comment: I would like to be sure of how the data column is formatted *in the csv files*.

Comment: Hi Serge, I've opened both historic and current file now. The data format for the date column seems to be set to Date -> UK Locale. Now, that is weird as when the dataset is merged together the current file keeps a date format of YYYY-MM-DD, whilst the historic file keeps a DD/MM/YYYY. When the historic file was combined the date values have been replaced with chr(10) for each cell - that was achieved using VBA - but of course this has happened well before I take ownership of this dataset

Comment: I do not know what means *Date -> UK Locale*. May be I could understand if you showed some lines from the csv files... Without knowing exactly what the output is, I cannot give advices on the possible processing.

Comment: Sorry, but I've posted already two example datasets with the data before code execution and the data after code execution. What span of data do you require?Something is happening in the current year's file as the dates are being formatted to YYYY-MM-DD for no reason. The historic file dates are untouched keeping a format of DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Before execution the data is in a csv format. What you show is not a csv format. Moreover, as csv is a text format, datatypes for a csv file have no meaning. What is your reason not to show the csv format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210323/discussion-between-makman-and-serge-ballesta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a big kudos to Serge Ballesta. You cannot imagine how many manhours of work you saved me and thank you for your kind explanations over our discussion.

Serge mentioned:

> Hint: you could ask pandas to parse the dates in the current file and
>   use `dt.strftime` to force the expected format

I've changed my function mergeit2 as follows:

I've imported the datetime library and changed a few lines below (see lines with comments)

```
import datetime

 def mergeit2(path1, path2):
         for fl in path1:
                df = pd.read_csv(fl, sep = ",", parse_dates = True) #Changed this line to include separator and parse_dates function.
                df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') #added this line to ensure Dates are recognised as strings and transformed to the shape I want
                dflist.append(df)
         concat2 = pd.concat(dflist, axis = 0)
         concat2.to_csv(path2,header = cols, index = False)
         df = pd.read_csv(path2)
         df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
         df.to_csv(path2, index = False)
```